# Adding group-specific text/data to faceted plot in R/ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am comparing the intra-group correlation between duplicate samples within a large gene expression experiment, where I have multiple separate biological groups - the idea being to see if any of the groups is much less well-correlated than the others, indicating a potential sample mixup or other error.

I am using ggplot to plot the expression values of each duplicate pair against each other. I would like to also be able to add the correlation coefficient and p-value to each panel of the plot, which I obtain through `summarize` and `cor.test`. You can use this code to get the general idea: in `exp1`, the duplicates are correlated, but not in `exp2`.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(exp=c(rep('exp1', 100), rep('exp2', 100)), a=rnorm(200, 1000, 200))
df <- mutate(df, b=ifelse(exp=='exp1', a*rnorm(100,1,0.05), rnorm(100, 1000, 200)))
head(df)
tail(df)

df %>% ggplot(aes(x=a, y=b))+
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~exp)

group_by(df, exp) %>% 
  summarize(corr=cor.test(a,b)$estimate, pval=cor.test(a,b)$p.value)
```

This is the plot I generated via `ggplot`, and I've manually added the R and p-values that I got at the end. But of course, if I have a lot of sample pairs to analyze, it would be nice to be able to add these automatically from within the `ggplot` call. I'm just not sure how to do it.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use the `stat_cor` function from the `ggpubr` package.

```
set.seed(123)

library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

df <- data.frame(exp=c(rep('exp1', 100), rep('exp2', 100)), a=rnorm(200, 1000, 200))
df <- mutate(df, b=ifelse(exp=='exp1', a*rnorm(100,1,0.05), rnorm(100, 1000, 200)))

ggplot(df, aes(x=a, y=b))+
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~exp) +
  stat_cor(method = "pearson")
```

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you very much. This is what my final plot with R2 values looks like - exactly what I was hoping to generate: https://imgur.com/a/v8T6zu3

Answer (score 5):

If, for whatever reason, you want to build this yourself instead of using the `ggpubr` functions, you can create your summary data, format labels, and place the labels with `geom_text`.

I'm formatting the stats so that R has a fixed 3 significant digits and p has 3 digits, falling back on scientific notation. I changed the names of those columns in `summarise` to R and p to make the labels below. Reshaping to long data and creating a new column with `unite` gets this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
...

group_by(df, exp) %>% 
  summarize(R = cor.test(a, b)$estimate, p = cor.test(a, b)$p.value) %>%
  mutate(R = formatC(R, format = "fg", digits = 3),
         p = formatC(p, format = "g", digits = 3)) %>%
  gather(key = measure, value = value, -exp) %>%
  unite("stat", measure, value, sep = " = ")
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>   exp   stat        
#>   <chr> <chr>       
#> 1 exp1  R = 0.965   
#> 2 exp2  R = 0.0438  
#> 3 exp1  p = 1.14e-58
#> 4 exp2  p = 0.665
```

Then for each of the groups, I want to collapse both labels, separated by a newline `\n`. This is a place that will scale well—you might have more summary stats to display, but this should still work.

```r
summ <- group_by(df, exp) %>% 
  summarize(R = cor.test(a, b)$estimate, p = cor.test(a, b)$p.value) %>%
  mutate(R = formatC(R, format = "fg", digits = 3),
         p = formatC(p, format = "g", digits = 3)) %>%
  gather(key = measure, value = value, -exp) %>%
  unite("stat", measure, value, sep = " = ") %>%
  group_by(exp) %>%
  summarise(both_stats = paste(stat, collapse = "\n"))

summ
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>   exp   both_stats               
#>   <chr> <chr>                    
#> 1 exp1  "R = 0.965\np = 1.14e-58"
#> 2 exp2  "R = 0.0438\np = 0.665"
```

In `geom_text`, I'm setting the x coordinate to `-Inf`, which gets the minimum of all x values, and the y coordinate as `Inf` for the maximum of all y values. That puts the label in the top-left corner, regardless of the values in the data.

The one thing I don't like here is then hacking the `hjust` and `vjust` outside their intended ranges of 0 to 1. But `nudge_x`/`nudge_y` won't do anything because of the values being set to infinity.

```r
df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = a, y = b)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(x = -Inf, y = Inf, label = both_stats), data = summ, 
            hjust = -0.1, vjust = 1.1, lineheight = 1) +
  facet_wrap(~ exp)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-11-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the detailed code breakdown - the `ggpubr` method is easy to carry out but it's hard to figure out exactly how it works. I appreciate that I can figure out how to tinker with your method.

Answer (score 4):

Similar to the answer of camille, but you can do all in one run

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)
df %>% 
  group_by(exp) %>% 
  mutate(p = cor.test(a, b)$p.value,
         rho = cor.test(a, b)$estimate) %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(p, rho), signif, 2) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=a, y=b)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_text(data = . %>% distinct(p, rho, exp), 
            aes(x = -Inf, y = Inf,label = paste("p=",p,"\nrho=",rho)),
            hjust = -0.1, vjust = 1.1, lineheight = 1) +
  facet_wrap(~exp)
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice - I would not have thought of using `distinct` like that but it totally makes sense.